# Differential forms vanishing at $T_p\mathbb S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I want to find differential 1-forms and 2-forms vanishing at $T_p\mathbb S^2$.
First of all, I find the the tangent plane $T_p\mathbb S^2$ to the sphere $\mathbb S^2$ given by the equation
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$
$\mathbb S^2$ is the level surface $f(x,y,z)=0$, where $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$. Hence, at any point $p=(x,y,z)\in\mathbb S^2$ the normalized gradient $\nabla f(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ is orthogonal to the surface. Therefore, the tangent space is the space in $\mathbb R^3$ orthogonal to the span of $\{p\}$. For example, let $p=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, then the tangent plane of the sphere at $p$ is given by
$$x_0x+y_0y+z_0z=1$$
Now, my question is, how is this related to the differential 1-forms and 2-forms on $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: This is like saying I'm interested in functions $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ such that $f(1)=0$. Don't you have any more specific requirements? Like a form vanishing on the whole tangent space to the whole sphere (even though this would still be quite broad)?

Comment: Well, I can consider the tanget space at a specific point $p$, e.g. $p=(1,0,0)$. My goal is to get a description of the differential forms vanishing at the tangent space in that point.

Comment: So, if the tangent plane is $x=0$, what $1$-forms on $\Bbb R^3$ will vanish on that subspace? What $2$-forms?

Comment: Also, given the differential form $\omega$ and $p\in\mathbb S^2$, $(\omega|_{\mathbb S^2})_p=0$ if and only if $\omega_p(X)=0$ for all $X\in T_p\mathbb S^2=\{X\in T_p\mathbb R^3:\langle X,N\rangle=0\}$, where $N=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$

Comment: @TedShifrin I understood your hint! Actually, by my previous comment, it is immediate.